# Live validation when in form are submit and cancel button

Tags: jquery, livevalidation

I have two buttons in form:

```
<input id="apply" type="submit" class="smgreen" name="apply" value="Apply">
<input id="cancel" type="submit" class="smred" name="cancel" value="Cancel">
```

and I need validate form live and on click of apply button, but no when I'l click on cancel button. How can I do it?

My JS:

```
f = {};
$('.required').each(function() {
  var id = $(this).prop('id');
  f[id] = new LiveValidation(id, { validMessage: "ok", wait: 500 } );
  f[id].add( Validate.Presence, { failureMessage: "error" } );
});
```

Comment: why do you want your cancel-button to submit the form?

Comment: Is the same when I change it to reset. My problem it does not solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a  handler event in your submit button, like this:

```
$('#apply').click(function(){
 f = {};
 $('.required').each(function() {
   var id = $(this).prop('id');
   f[id] = new LiveValidation(id, { validMessage: "ok", wait: 500 } );
   f[id].add( Validate.Presence, { failureMessage: "error" } );
 });
});
```

Comment: It does not work when first time click on apply and then to cancel

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not making "Cancel" a  "submit" button. Think about it... you're not really submitting anything if you want to cancel.

Also, if you insist on having multiple submit buttons, give them a more generic name:

```
<input id="apply"  type="submit" name="action" value="Apply" />
<input id="cancel" type="submit" name="action" value="Cancel" />
```

As far as your JavaScript goes, don't validate on button-click, but on form-submit:

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // do validation stuff
    if( valid ) {
        $(this).submit();
    } else {
        // do something about your errors
    }
});
```

Comment: And what is valid variable?

Comment: However it is you identify whether the form is valid or not.

Comment: It does not work ... livevalidation still block cancel button